# Open explorer during a screensaver, erratic behaviour

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-10

I have a screensaver which is basically drawing pictures one after the other.
Each of these pictures are in a main folder that has a lot of subfolders.
I would like that, by pressing a button ("E"), the application opens the specific subfolder (i'm passing through the whole image path & file called `imgpath`.
This is what i did so far (key_down) :

```
 case Keys.E:
                string directoryName = Path.GetDirectoryName(imgpath);
                Process.Start(directoryName);
                Application.Exit();
                break;
```

This works fine when i'm running the app from visual studio, as well as if i'm double clicking the scr file that i generated (after renaming it from exe to scr) but what's funny is that it doesnt work when Windows 10 run this as a screen saver. When i click on "E", the screensaver just stops.

What i tried is to comment the application.exit() and then the explorer pops up well but i still have the screensaver in the background and when i move my mouse, the screensver stops and the explorer quits as well.
Anyway to open that explorer independantly from the application itself ?

Thanks.

Comment: I suspect the surrounding screensaver logic already quits the screensaver on keypress. Seeing that surrounding logic might help in identifying how/if that behavior can be altered.

Comment: not sure i understood but i have 'Application.Exit()' when i move the mouse or mouseDown plus in that case Key.E and finally in the 'default:  Application.Exit();  break;' of the key_press event.

Comment: Screensavers have a bunch of pre-existing logic that you're probably not correctly overriding. But this is just a guess as the question only very selectively shows one particular case of a switch case and there's no surrounding context.

Comment: ok, but difficult to copy paste the whole code, what, do you think, would be more relevant ? the application.exit occurences ?